# BokehScheduler not working on cent OS

Tags: bokeh, dask

BokehScheduler is not working with these versions:

```
bokeh==0.12.6
dask==0.15.0
distributed==1.17.0
tornado==4.4.0
```

this setup works perfectly on Windows 7 with same packages and versions in a virtual env.

Error:

```
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Could not launch service: ('bokeh', 8787)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py", line 404, in start_services
service = v(self, io_loop=self.loop)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/bokeh/scheduler.py", line 995, in __init__
scheduler)))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/application/handlers/function.py", line 11, in __init__
_check_callback(func, ('doc',))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/util/callback_manager.py", line 12, in _check_callback
sig = signature(callback)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/util/future.py", line 85, in signature
for name in func.keywords.keys():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

This is has been working on below packages:

```
Bokeh==0.12.5
dask==0.14.3
distributed==1.16.3
tornado==4.4.0
```

Comment: I recommend raising this as an issue on the Bokeh issue tracker at [https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/new](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/new)

Comment: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6512 There is already this issue.